# The fio shows iops very less for CentOS6.0 vm running in kvm with backend disk SSD

Tags: performance, centos6, iops

Disk "iops" is very less with "fio" disk benchmark tool for CentOS 6.0 virtual machine running on KVM.  When I execute same on CentOS 6.7 and CentOS 7.2, the iops is as expected. The back end disk is SSD and the command I executed is below.

## fio --name=randwrite --randrepeat=1 --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --rw=randwrite --size=4g --iodepth=64 --ioengine=libaio --output=fio_op1.txt.

I have installed virtio module as guided by the below kb.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/ch10s04.html

The #lsmod  | grep -i virtio* shows all the modules also.

iops for CentOS6.0
[image]
iops for CentOS6.7
[image]
iops for CentOS7.2
[image]

Comment: Why would you be using CentOS 6.0 anymore when you have newer versions available?

Comment: CentOS 6.0 is the one customer used in previous infrastructure and he is particular that he needs same CentOS6.0.

Comment: The very FIRST thing you need to do is to find out why he is insisting on this, and then deal with that, because quite frankly it's insane.